# Arrays Vs Vector During Recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, binary-tree, pass-by-reference

I have some doubt between array and vector in the following binary tree code.

The following is the code to find 
**Print all nodes that are at distance k from a leaf node**

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int> visited)
{

    if(temp->left==NULL&&temp->right==NULL)
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);

        if(visited[v.size()-k-1]==0)
        {
            visited[v.size()-k-1]=1;
            cout<<v[v.size()-k-1]<<"\n";
        }

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);
        visited.push_back(0);
    }

    TraceLeaves(temp->left,k,v,visited);

    TraceLeaves(temp->right,k,v,visited);

}

int main()
{
    root = createnode(1);
    root->left=createnode(2);
    root->right=createnode(3);
    root->left->left = createnode(4);
    root->left->right = createnode(5);
    root->right->left = createnode(6);
    root->right->right = createnode(7);
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> visited;
    TraceLeaves(root,1,v,visited);
}
```

The output of the above method is

```
2
2
3
3
```

When i replace the **vector visited** array with **bool visited[]**

like

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,bool visited[])
{

    if(temp->left==NULL&&temp->right==NULL)
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);

        if(visited[v.size()-k-1]==0)
        {
            visited[v.size()-k-1]=1;
            cout<<v[v.size()-k-1]<<"\n";
        }

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);
        visited[v.size()-1]=0;
    }

    TraceLeaves(temp->left,k,v,visited);

    TraceLeaves(temp->right,k,v,visited);

}

int main()
{
    root = createnode(1);
    root->left=createnode(2);
    root->right=createnode(3);
    root->left->left = createnode(4);
    root->left->right = createnode(5);
    root->right->left = createnode(6);
    root->right->right = createnode(7);
    vector<int> v;
    bool visited[5]={false};
    TraceLeaves(root,1,v,visited);
}
```

I am getting

```
2
3
```

which is actually correct..

So i searched in the online.. which tells me that

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int> visited)
```

should be replaced with

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int> &visited)
```

The complete after this change is

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root;

node* createnode(int d)
{
    node *New;
    New = new node;
    New->data = d;
    New->left=NULL;
    New->right=NULL;
}

void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int>& visited)
{

    if(temp->left==NULL&&temp->right==NULL)
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);

        if(visited[v.size()-k-1]==0)
        {
            visited[v.size()-k-1]=1;
            cout<<v[v.size()-k-1]<<"\n";
        }

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        v.push_back(temp->data);
        visited.push_back(0);
    }

    TraceLeaves(temp->left,k,v,visited);

    TraceLeaves(temp->right,k,v,visited);

}

int main()
{
    root = createnode(1);
    root->left=createnode(2);
    root->right=createnode(3);
    root->left->left = createnode(4);
    root->left->right = createnode(5);
    root->right->left = createnode(6);
    root->right->right = createnode(7);
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> visited(5,0);
    TraceLeaves(root,1,v,visited);
}
```

but it gives me output

```
2
```

as we are using array by reference means  changes will be updated

2 ,3 are in the same level .So only 2 is getting printed.

So my question is

why am i getting 2,3 as output when bool visited[] is used in the code and passed by reference and getting only 2 when vector &v is used
??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you do `visited.push_back(0)` with `bool visited[]` (keeping the same pointer) ?

Comment: visited[v.size()-1]=0 as we have to add at the end only.

Comment: Just the mere fact that `push_back` *increases* the size of the number of entries, and arrays *cannot* be resized is enough of a difference to make both code samples, well, different.  If you sized the vector the same as the array up front, then there would be (or should be) no difference.

Comment: `visited[v.size()-1]=0` -- which could be replaced with the more intuitive `visited.back() = 0;`

Comment: Here i am getting different output for vector.
Can you tell me how to get 2,3 output with the help of vector.
If i use pass-by-reference means it is resulting 2 only
but when we pass the bool array by reference means we are getiing 2,3

Comment: Now I have edited the post by including  bool visited[] code, just have a look..!! @PaulMcKenzie @ Jarod42

Comment: This: `void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,bool visited[])`  is no different than this: `void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,bool *visited);`  The last parameter is a pointer, no matter how much it looks like an array.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between

```
bool visited[5]={false};
```

and

```
vector<int> visited;
```

besides the obvious C-style array vs `std::vector`. In the first case the array has exactly 5 elements, all initialized with `false`. In the second case, the vector is empty and you're not inserting anything into it anywhere (at least not in the code you've shown). So in this case, when you access `visited[v.size()-k-1]` in that function, you're trying to read and change elements that don't exist, which is undefined behavior.

To get the same behavior when using an `std::vector` you should initialize it with the same elements before using it.

Comment: Actually visited[v.size(0-k-1] is referred only at the leaf node.
So before reaching the leaf node, visited array will be inserted with some elements.
[Check in the else block]

So no problem regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note:**

You have undefined behavior in your `createNode` function.  You are not returning a value, yet the function is supposed to return a `node*`.   You need to address this issue before proceeding.

---

First, you have to realize that both of the examples you posted are fundamentally different, not just different because you used a vector in the first example and then an array in the second example.

First, an array cannot be resized.  Thus your first example does this when `visited` is an a vector:

```
 visited.push_back(0); // resizes
```

This is a major difference between that line and this (in your array example):

```
 visited[v.size()-1]=0;  // does not resize
```

So we could have stopped right here with the differences in the two examples.  However here is the other difference:

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int> visited)
```

Here, the `visited` is a vector passed by value.  This means that any changes in `TraceLeaves` that happen to the `visited` vector are local, and are not reflected back to the caller.

Compare it to this in your array example:

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,bool visited[])
```

The `visited` parameter is a `bool *`.  The `[]` syntax does not change this fact.  So the declaration above is the same as this:

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,bool* visited)
```

This is *much* different than the `vector` version above.  What you're doing here is passing a pointer to `visited`, thus changes you make to the `visited` "array" *will* reflect back to the caller.

---

If you really want to have both examples to be the same, you have to write them to be the same, not different.  First, you size the vector to the same size as the array example.  In `main`:

```
std::vector<bool> visited(5,false);
```

Then the `TraceLeaves` function would look *exactly* the same as the array example, with the difference being the function prototype to mimic the pointer example:

```
void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int>& visited)
```

[Live Example with changes described above](http://ideone.com/Vpxq2q)

Comment: I have made these two changes to vector code,

    vector<int> visited(5,0);
and 
   void TraceLeaves(node *temp,int k,vector<int> v,vector<int>& visited)

but still i am getting only 2 as output..

As mentioned in the post , I have already checked passing vector by reference :)

Comment: Now i placed complete code in the post sir. Do check once :)

Comment: @sai  See my update.  You should fix your `createNode` function, as it is not returning a value.

Comment: @sai Please read my answer carefully.  You are still calling `push_back` when you shouldn't be.  Your code using the vector should be **exactly** the same as the array version.  This means that you should also be doing this: `visited[v.size() - 1] = 0;` in the array version **and** in the vector version.  The only difference would be that the vector is passed by reference to your function, and that the vector must have a size of 5 before the call.  Once you do that, then you will have equivalent code.

Comment: Thank you so much :) :) @PaulMcKenzie for pointing my mistakes.
It worked.
Also I found different approach like, first keep an empty vector,pass it through reference,now you can use visited.push_back(0)

but at the end of code ,you should also put visited.pop_back() else the 0 will stay in the vector even when move to another path. :) :)